How to endow a cross normed tensor product $C^*$ - algebra with a structure of $G$ - $C^*$ - algebra?
Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ two topological groups which are locally compact, Hausdorff, and second countable.
Let $A_1$ ( resp. $A_2$ ) a $G_1$ - $C^*$ - algebra ( resp. $G_2$ - $C^*$ - algebra ).
Let $A_1 \otimes_{ \alpha } A_2$ a cross normed tensor product $C^*$ - algebra of $A_1$ and $A_2$.
How to endow $A_1 \otimes_{ \alpha } A_2$ with a structure of $G$ - $C^*$ - algebra with $G$, a locally compact, Hausdorff, and second countable topological group, where $G$ expresses in terms of $G_1$ and $G_2$ ? ( Can we take $ G = G_1 \times G_2 $ ? )
Thanks in advance for your help.
